# XSL string multi-replace function

Tags: xml, string, function, xslt, replace

how to make this function do multi-replacing ?
exp: replace `aaa` with `111` and replace `bbb` with `222` ...etc

```
<xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
  <xsl:with-param name="text" select="sm:changefreq"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'aaa'" />
  <xsl:with-param name="with" select="'111ً'"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="replace-string">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="replace"/>
    <xsl:param name="with"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$with"/>
        <xsl:call-template name="replace-string">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="with" select="$with"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**@Mads Hansen**
i am newbie ..
are the final codes will be like the codes bellow ?

**index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<t>The quick
brown fox</t>
```

**index.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <my:params xml:space="preserve">
        <pattern>
            <old>&#xA;</old>
            <new><br/></new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>quick</old>
            <new>slow</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>fox</old>
            <new>elephant</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>brown</old>
            <new>white</new>
        </pattern>
    </my:params>

    <xsl:variable name="vPats"
         select="document('')/*/my:params/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pPatterns" select="$vPats"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
            <xsl:variable name="vPat" select=
            "$vPats[starts-with($pText, old)][1]"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($vPat)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$vPat/new/node()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                "substring($pText, 1 + not($vPat) + string-length($vPat/old/node()))"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Check out functx for things like this.  http://www.functx.com/  For your specific need they have http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/functx_replace-multi.html

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 solution to the multiple-replace problem**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <my:params xml:space="preserve">
        <pattern>
            <old>&#xA;</old>
            <new><br/></new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>quick</old>
            <new>slow</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>fox</old>
            <new>elephant</new>
        </pattern>
        <pattern>
            <old>brown</old>
            <new>white</new>
        </pattern>
    </my:params>

    <xsl:variable name="vPats"
         select="document('')/*/my:params/*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()" name="multiReplace">
        <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="pPatterns" select="$vPats"/>

        <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
            <xsl:variable name="vPat" select=
            "$vPats[starts-with($pText, old)][1]"/>

            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($vPat)">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="substring($pText,1,1)"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$vPat/new/node()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:call-template name="multiReplace">
                <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
                "substring($pText, 1 + not($vPat) + string-length($vPat/old/node()))"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>The quick
brown fox</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced** (quick -> slow, brown -> white, fox -> elephant, NL -> `<br/>`):

```
The slow<br />white elephant
```

**Explanation**:

1. A named template that calls itself recursively is used.
2. All multiple replacement pattern --> replacement pairs are provided in a single external parameter, which for convenience here is specified inline as the global-level element `<my:params>` .
3. The recursion takes every single character in the source string (from left to right) and finds the first pattern that starts with this character at this position in the string.
4. The replacement can be not only a string but also any node. In this specific case we are replacing every NL character with a `<br/>` element.