# replace a character with a set of characters and display message in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Input:

```
<Data>
    <info>the %text ^with *special chars asxbajx @ fagfa ~</info>   
</Data>
```

output:

```
<Data>
    <info> the ++text ++with ++special chars asxbajx ++ fagfa ++</info>
</Data>
```

Requirement:

Search for some particluar set of characters and replace them with the text "++". If the charecter is encountered need to display message to user.

xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="aaa">

          <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
          <my:pNames>
            <n>%</n>
            <n>^</n>
            <n>*</n>
            <n>@</n>
            <n>~</n>
          </my:pNames>

          <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:template>

          <xsl:template match="text()">

            <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>


            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n">

              <xsl:variable name="testvar1" select="."/>    
              <xsl:if test="contains($pText,$testvar1)">
                <xsl:message terminate="no">
                 <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
                </xsl:message>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>


            <xsl:variable name="testvar" select="document('')/*/my:pNames"/>

            <xsl:value-of select="
                    translate(
                        .,
                        $testvar,
                        '+'
                        )
                    "/>

          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not getting the exact output.

Can any one help me.

Comment: This question and answer may be what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499931/xsl-string-multi-replace-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you have is that the **translate** function only 'translates' occurences a single character to another single character. So you can't use it to replace the single character `%` with the double-character string `++`. Furthermore, you typically have the second and third arguments the same length

```
translate(., '%^*@~', '+++++')
```

This is because the 'from' characters are replaced by the character in the corresponding position in the 'to' string. If you were to do just translate(., '%^*@~', '+') then the characters `^*@~` get replaced with nothing!

XSLT1.0 doesn't have a replace function (one exists in XSTL2.0 though), so firstly you will need to hunt down a recursive template to do the job. Here's one!

```
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
 <xsl:param name="text"/>
 <xsl:param name="replace"/>
 <xsl:param name="by"/>
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
     <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
       <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Rather than call it for each of your parameters in turn, one thing you could first make use of the translate function to replace all your funny characters to just one funny character (for example, `%`)

First define a variable to hold the first of your character parameters

```
<xsl:variable name="firstchar" select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n[1]" />
```

Then define two variables like so

```
  <xsl:variable name="testvar">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n" mode="replace"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="replace">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n" mode="by"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

The corresponding templates for this would look like this

```
<xsl:template match="my:pNames/n" mode="replace">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="my:pNames/n" mode="by">
   <xsl:value-of select="$firstchar"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This means the **testvar** variable will be set to `%^*@~`, and **replace** will be set to `+++++`. You can then use the **translate** function to replace all occurences of the funny characters to just the same character

```
translate(., $testvar, $replace)
```

This then means you only need to call the replace template only once

```
  <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(., $testvar, $replace)" />
     <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$firstchar" />
     <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'++'" />
  </xsl:call-template>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:my="aaa">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <my:pNames>
      <n>%</n>
      <n>^</n>
      <n>*</n>
      <n>@</n>
      <n>~</n>
   </my:pNames>

   <xsl:variable name="firstchar" select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n[1]" />

   <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="text()">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n">
         <xsl:variable name="testvar1" select="."/>
         <xsl:if test="contains($pText,$testvar1)">
            <xsl:message terminate="no">
               <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
            </xsl:message>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>

      <xsl:variable name="testvar">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n" mode="replace"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:variable name="replace">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/*/my:pNames/n" mode="by"/>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
         <xsl:with-param name="text" select="translate(., $testvar, $replace)" />
         <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$firstchar" />
         <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'++'" />
      </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="my:pNames/n" mode="replace">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="my:pNames/n" mode="by">
      <xsl:value-of select="$firstchar"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
     <xsl:param name="text"/>
     <xsl:param name="replace"/>
     <xsl:param name="by"/>
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="contains($text,$replace)">
         <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="$by"/>
         <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
           <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,$replace)"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace"/>
           <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by"/>
         </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<Data>
   <info>the ++text ++with ++special chars asxbajx ++ fagfa ++</info>
</Data>
```